# RSS feed for my "Recent Activity" page?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, feed

Something I've wanted since the day the "Responses" tab was added: An RSS feed for replies to my questions/answers..

There's feeds for about everything else, but not this.. The obvious problem is authentication with OpenID, since you need to be logged into access the feed.

One possible solution to this is, protect the feed URL with a unique token. This is how many private torrent trackers resolve authenticated feeds. Basically the RSS feed address would be something like `http://example.com/users/recent/0/recent.rss?token=94ff6f5039d60ea569182dcd3e64df7c` and the user would have a "regenerate token" button should they wish to invalidate the old feed address.

*(the email responses option isn't what I'm looking for, and routing the emails through an email->RSS system seems kind of.. backwards)*

Comment: so is there solution for that or I missed it?

Comment: @Radek No. Nothing yet..

Comment: it would be great if @Jeff Atwood could make some comments on that. I'm sure he can make hundreds of people happy :-)

Comment: flickr also uses the token approach although they call theirs "secret"

Comment: This is sorely needed. It's been intentionally left out.

Comment: +1 for the feature request

Comment: Note [Jeff's statement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62588/rss-overhaul-desperately-needed/104673#104673): *we are moving away from RSS to more email and web-based solutions to some of these things these days -- like newsletter subscriptions and tag subscriptions.* and see the nice Stack2RSS in that same post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The activity tab on your profile/activity ( `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/<number>/`) has a RSS Feed.

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is the same thing dbr asked for. It seems the feed on this tab is the same that's on the user's main profile page, which is a "feed of the 30 latest questions, answers, and comments from this user". What they're asking is for a "RSS feed for replies to my questions/answers".

Answer (score 12):

I agree with this, it would help me keep up with responses to my questions.  Plenty of other sites use the token method without any problems.

I'd especially like to see this implemented in tandem with [this suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have), so I'd know when someone has responded to a comment I left somewhere.

Answer (score 8):

Why not just having an opt-in preference to allow all my "Recent Activity" be public and set a regular RSS feed on it?

I would sure use it, while there is no **instant** e-mail notification. Though I've been using [Newt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40927/how-do-you-do-to-keep-track-of-notifications/87528#87528) for a while.

Comment: Go here: http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/{userID}

Comment: @random you again! :P c'mon, this is not "recent activity". By the way, I just noticed meta doesn't have a feed even for that! o_O

Comment: Are you saying this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/143411 doesn't show your recent activity? Otherwise, complete your sentence.

Comment: That's the second half of what I meant, but it wasn't showing! Now your link does. Maybe I miss-spelled something. My bad. o_O It's still not the "Recent Activity" (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/recent/143411) I meant. That's just *my* activity.

Comment: Okay, you're talking recent responses directed at you. That's different.

Comment: Not just responses. It's on the question title and that "/users/recent/" link: **"Recent Activity"** - But yeah. :)

Comment: Naming is bad, but the envelope is information directed at you only and only you really get to see that.

Comment: And what I'm saying is that I don't care if it's public, specially if it means better functionality for myself.

Answer (score 3):

I created a feedfier for the user's recent activity page (the envelope button): http://code.google.com/p/authfeed/

Comment: not working anymore ;-( I talked to the author of the code

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays there is a per-site feed, the "user feed", linked in the bottom right corner of the "info" tab, sub-tab "stats". One could follow [just anyone](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/84237), and the icon and link are always shown to everybody. So: no authentication required at all.

(Likewise for your responses, or [anyone's responses](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/84237/responses) for that matter, even though for responses the icon and link are *shown* on your own profile only.)

Comment: Does this means my suggestion was "accepted" without the opt-in part? :P

Comment: (@Cawas, did you [see this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62588/rss-overhaul-desperately-needed/104673#104673)?)

Comment: I have seen stack2rss and similar amazing stuff from George (who's Nathan?), but not that official post. But I must say Newt has been much nicer to me than RSS could ever be. And I'm really glad to read the email hater man himself prioritize it over the sacred RSS. Still hoping for a brither future on mail notifications! And thanks for the heads up!! :)