# Email notifications should be sent to commenters when replies are posted to their comments

Tags: feature-request, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make recent activity and responses show new comments on questions/answers I have commented on (even if I don’t own them)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have)

Email notifications should be sent to commenters when replies (or questions) are posted to their comments. Otherwise comments which need followup will have loose ends and the question might not get an approved answer (question gets abandoned prematurely).

Comment: Someone asked this already: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1206/notify-comments-for-comments

Comment: Dunno about email, but some form of notification of further comments would be nice. But only in some cases where you specifically opt-in for notifications, by default it's fine as it is.

Comment: I asked for something similar to @Jonik: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have

Answer (score 0):

If this is even considered, it should only be after a long period of account inactivity.  I'll throw out one week as a starting point.  It should also be disable-able on your user preferences page.  I don't need dozens of notification emails from a site I visit every day. :)

Comment: Why limit this to long inactivity? Some of us don't check old questions every day just to see if someone replied. I like instant notifications. If you don't want this, just turn it off.