# How do I track people answering my comments?

Tags: support, comments, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suggestion - notify user when their name is mentioned in comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2035/suggestion-notify-user-when-their-name-is-mentioned-in-comment)

How do I track when people comment on an answer after me (it may be a reply to me)? Or when I comment the question asking for clarification, how do I see that they have updated?

This of course without having to visit all the places I have commented to see if there is a comment "answer".

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2035/suggestion-notify-user-when-their-name-is-mentioned-in-comment

Comment: For those coming later, as I did, and wondering how this can be seen: At the top left of every StackExchange site is a `StackExchange` button. If it has a red number beside it, there are notifications/messages waiting for you. Click on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a good way currently, but there are feature requests and discussions about ways to improve the system, linked in the comments.