# Comments with the @ (at) symbol before the user name triggers something?

Tags: support, comments, notifications, semantics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

In Twitter the at (@) symbol makes the tweet appear in the user page.

Does it do anything on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It does not do anything as far as programming. It is just a social construct we have all adopted to show who we are addressing our comment at.

And now, [it also notifies the target](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2035/notify-user-when-their-name-is-mentioned-in-comment-closed):

> Normally, you only get notified of comments when you own the post.
>
> You will now get notified of any comments that refer to you by **@username** in a comment, even if you do not own the post.
>
> Rules:
>
> 1. Only applies to other people in the comments that you are commenting on.
> 2. **Response must include @username that you are referring to**, where "username" is a reasonable match to the user's current display name (as seen in the comments above yours).
> 3. There must be a starts-with, case insensitive match of at least THREE characters to the displayname. So @a and @ab will never match anyone or anything.
> 4. Spaces cannot be used to match, so if the person's display name is "Peter Smith" then just use @peter to match.
> 5. Matching is performed in reverse chronological order, so if there are five people named "John" in the comments, writing "hey @john, have you considered apples?" will match the *most recent* John to comment.
> 6. Only one person can be replied to at a time in a comment. The first one "in" wins.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have discusses this. "the "notify when people say my name" is really interesting, but requires unique names which we don't enforce"

Comment: it's just the twitter construct, the original meaning of `@` is the `at sign`, it has been traditionaly used to denote host in URIs. i don't see a reason to use `@` in this context in different places. i also wonder if it really triggers something, when used in stackoverflow comments

Answer (score 4):

I would back the idea of having the @[USERNAME] actually try to predict the user being addressed and place a link to their profile.  Overall though, @TheTXI is correct, it is becoming a social construct (thanks to twitter) that we are beginning to adopt and adapt into other tools.

Comment: I still haven't quite fallen into it. I notice that I am still one of the few people who addresses people using the "[UserName]:" prefix instead of "@[UserName]"

Comment: you shall give in....  the construct will overwhelm you :)