# What is the relevance of "@" in comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, symbols

Why do users use *@* ("commercial at," or "at sign") in their comments?
Does it actually route the comment to the name provided after the *@*?
What is the right format of using it?

Comment: Mentioned here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5961/comments-with-the-at-symbol-before-the-user-name-triggers-something

Comment: `@` is pronounced as `at`. Does it make sense now? :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do comment replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Answer (score 10):

It's just a convention of referring specifically to a user within the stream of comments.

Twitter maxed it out popularity-wise, but it's been lingering mainly on blog comments where you would have the other commenters talking to each other and not being in a threaded view.

A [recently completed feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2035/notify-user-when-their-name-is-mentioned-in-comment-closed) now means that the convention does something:

> Normally, you only get notified of comments when you own the post.
>
> You will now get notified of any comments that refer to you by **@username** in a comment, even if you do not own the post.
>
> Rules:
>
> 1. Only applies to other people in the comments that you are commenting on.
> 2. **Response must include @username that you are referring to**, where "username" is a reasonable match to the user's current display name (as seen in the comments above yours).
> 3. There must be a starts-with, case insensitive match of at least THREE characters to the displayname. So @a and @ab will never match anyone or anything.
> 4. Spaces cannot be used to match, so if the person's display name is "Peter Smith" then just use @peter to match.
> 5. Matching is performed in reverse chronological order, so if there are five people named "John" in the comments, writing "hey @john, have you considered apples?" will match the *most recent* John to comment.
> 6. Only one person can be replied to at a time in a comment. The first one "in" wins.

Comment: If I post a comment to an answer on SO or MSO with the @Name symbol will the Name person be notified about it?

Comment: No, they won't. Not unless you're posting under their post.

Comment: @AeonFlux - This example will **not** show up in your recent comments as linked by the envelope up top.

Comment: yeah it didn't, so we have to keep polling our answers to see new comments! that's cumbersome... no way of getting alerts on new comments?

Comment: Self-poll yes. There's been requests here and there to allow for you to be notified in a same vein. One such is of all the comments on posts you've posted: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have (post)

Comment: What happens if I @myself?

Comment: @Isaac Nothing will happen.