# How to comment @Someone With Spaces

Tags: discussion, support, comments, global-inbox

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is the syntax of @username in comments when username has spaces?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36026/what-is-the-syntax-of-username-in-comments-when-username-has-spaces)
>   [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

A user named "Someone With Spaces" comments on my post.  I want to comment back and have it show up in his inbox.  I comment back with "@Someone With Spaces, bla bla bla".  Is this correct protocol?

Comment: click the help link next to every comment input area; the specific thing you are asking about is shown there.

Comment: @Jeff To me, it's not apparent by that help text that the user "Peter Smith" (i.e. with a space) is being abbreviated - it seems quite plausible that the user's name could simply be "PeterSmith"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JeffAtwood discusses the methodology of commenting here: [Syntax of commenting with usernames that have spaces](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36026/what-is-the-syntax-of-username-in-comments-when-username-has-spaces).