# Referring To Other Users

Tags: discussion, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the relevance of “ @ ” in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21866/what-is-the-relevance-of-in-comments)

Apologies if this has already been asked. I noticed that when user's refer to others there is an "@" in front of their display name. So if some one was referring to my display name, it would read "@AGoodDisplayName".

My questions are:

1. Is this done by stackoverflow/markdown?
2. If so, how to do it (or is this just a convention that people are using?

Comment: I think it is normally used in comments, mostly to indicate that the comment is targeting a particular person/comment/answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a convention people use. StackOverflow uses the @Username to notify users of comment responses.

See [Jeff's post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have/35913#35913) about the criteria for users being notified.

Comment: Exactly what I needed to know, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that at sign (@) is a convention used on Stack Overflow to address other people. The developers have taken that "convention" and made it a [functional direct-reply mechanism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have/35913#35913).

But the convention started in other social media.

The first place where it became the social norm, I believe, was in IRC <sup>[*citation needed* :) ]</sup>. Participants would use the `@` symbol to refer to other folks in the discussion by their nickname.

I believe the convention was adapted from e-mail, where @ was used to mark a passage as "attention" to someone (other than the main recipient) in the cc: list. If I was sending a message to Jeff about Waffle Wednesday, I might also cc my assistant, Marc. The message would look something like this:

```
To: Jeff
cc: Marc

I ordered sixteen dozen waffles for the office. They should be here by 10am.

@Marc, please confirm.

Rob
```

The `@` symbol had no *functional* purpose in email. It was simply convention.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it easier to do this, and you are using Firefox, you might want to look into these two Greasemonkey scripts:

- [Script to add “reply” links to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38600/script-to-add-reply-links-to-comments)
- [GreaseMonkey script to assist twitter-style @replies in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30085/greasemonkey-script-to-assist-twitter-style-replies-in-comments)