# What is the purpose of placing '@' before a members name?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is the relevance of “@” in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21866/what-is-the-relevance-of-in-comments)
>   [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

The title says it all. I noticed this in a lot of comments and answers. I'm not sure what the purpose is though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The @reply allows a person to direct their comment to another user (one who has participated in the question (by editing, replying, or commenting). The system is able to send that comment to the target user and it appears in their inbox.

See: [What is the relevance of "@" in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21866/what-is-the-relevance-of-in-comments)