# Add notification when someone comments in the same post than me

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, notifications

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Notify user when their name is mentioned in comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2035/notify-user-when-their-name-is-mentioned-in-comment)
>   [Make recent activity and responses show new comments on questions/answers I have commented on (even if I don’t own them)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have)

Like Facebook does (and no, the suggestion is not about turning SO into facebook) I'd like to see a notification in the recent activity tab when there is a new comment to a post I previously posted a comment to, this way I can follow up.

Currently there's no easy way to see it other than go to the recent tab and manually check every post you commented on.

Comment: Suggested several times before, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have being one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, you only get notified of comments when you own the post.

You will now get notified of any comments that refer to you by **@username** in a comment, even if you do not own the post.

Rules:

1. Only applies to other people in the comments that you are commenting on.
2. **Response must include @username that you are referring to**, where "username" is a reasonable match to the user's current display name (as seen in the comments above yours).
3. There must be a starts-with, case insensitive match of at least THREE characters to the displayname. So @a and @ab will never match anyone or anything.
4. Spaces cannot be used to match, so if the person's display name is "Peter Smith" then just use @peter to match.
5. Matching is performed in reverse chronological order, so if there are five people named "John" in the comments, writing "hey @john, have you considered apples?" will match the *most recent* John to comment.

Comment: Wow, is it Christmas already?

Comment: @hardcoded Have you considered oranges?

Comment: I guess my current user name is due to a new change. Thank you very much, muchísimas gracias, domo arigato gozaimazu, muito obrigado, большое спасибо, mulţumesc foarte mult @Je.