# Notify me of edits to posts I've voted on

Tags: feature-request, notifications

Please add an option to get notifications if questions or answers I've voted on have been edited (and as an extra bonus, commented upon). Right now, notifications are limited to questions marked as favourite. For others, I have to go through my activity to check for responses to my comments, for example. That's time-consuming, and unfun.

Comment: See lots of the questions in the related links section. Like - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43451/notification-on-edited-answers and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41507/notification-when-a-question-or-answer-is-revised-is-not-really-status-completed and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16662/add-notification-when-someone-comments-in-the-same-post-than-me

Comment: Be aware you might just get what you're looking for...

Comment: And cowbell. We definitely need more cowbell.

Comment: @Popular Demand, excellent edit. Real nice.

Answer (score 4):

No, this would do more harm than good. Some people use up all 30 of their daily allotment of votes on a fairly regular basis. Under your proposal, the volume of notifications would be so large that the whole system would lose value.

Even users who don't vote often will have voted on thousands of posts over the course of several years. Old questions may not generate many notifications, but the ones they do generate are likely to be of little value.

Also, you say

> For others, I have to go through my Activity to check if there were response to my Comments, for example.

This won't happen if people write `@Tshepang` in their replies. If they're not doing that, it's a problem with user behavior, not a problem with available features, and that calls for a different solution.

Comment: That's why I stated that this should be optional.

Comment: @Tshepang, true, you said it should be an option. Making it an option doesn't make the feature more useful for those who choose to opt in, though.

Comment: I don't get what you are saying. Making it an option make the feature useful for those, like me, who want it.

Comment: @Tshepang, true again, an opt-in system won't actively hurt those who don't opt in. Adding features to a system isn't free, though. It takes time and effort to design, implement and test features, the system's overall complexity goes up a tick, it's one more thing that has to be supported forever and considered when other feature requests are made, &c. So, new features need a certain amount of utility to get approved, and it's my opinion that this doesn't pass the test.

Comment: Nice edit @Patrick it inspired me to write [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/482874/get-posts-starting-with-1) to find more. Only 3 here on MSE, edited all of them now. :)

Comment: Nice @sha. And thanks.

Comment: No problem, was surprised to see no such posts on MSO. Guess people there catch it on time and edit it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

As a start, you could check out the [StackStalker](https://stackapps.com/questions/493/stackstalker-be-notified-when-your-question-is-updated-chrome-extension) Chrome extension.  You add a question to the list and it discreetly notifies you of any changes.  It includes comments but not up/down votes.

You could also combine this [SO Live!](https://stackapps.com/questions/1703/so-live-live-updates-to-your-reputation-score) which updates your rep and displays a message in the top bar.

[image]

Comment: The notifications for when specific Questions have been Up/Downvoted is too verbose. I'm more interested in changes in their content.

Answer (score -2):

Please don't.  The noise this would create for those of us who are active on multiple sites would be immense.  Especially edit-happy sites like [rpg](http://rpg.stackexchange.com) or [SO](http://stackoverflow.) for that matter.

Comment: @C. Ross, This will be an opt-in kind of thing. That's why I said "add an option".