# Allow me to get notifications on specific down-voted questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, down-votes

Related to (but narrower than) [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68106/167443):

Often times when a post is downvoted, it is because it is unclear, ambiguous, poorly written, or in general close-worthy. These are posts that are not likely to ever be favorited (in their current state). There are also posts that have a decent chance to be edited to improve any of the aforementioned negative facets.

I propose that we be allowed, when downvoting a question, to recieve a notification after it has been approved (under the specifications named below). This would be a better alternative to "favoriting" a poor question which may or may not actually be improved.

Draft proposed feature:

- When I downvote a question, I am asked (no more obtrusively than the suggested share link on an upvote) if I would like to be notified if/when the post is improved.
- I will receive at most one notification regarding post improvement (or no notifications if no improvement is made).
- I will receive a notification between 24-48 hours after I downvote and agree to a notifcation. I will only receive this notification if the post has been edited at least once since I downvoted.
- If the post is not edited within 48 hours after my vote, I will not be notified.
- Regardless of the open/closed status of the question when I voted, if the post has been closed and edited (or edited and closed), a reopen vote will trigger the notification.

Basically I can opt in (at the time of voting) to be notified if a question I downvote is "improved" according to certain metrics (what I've proposed here or an otherwise suitable measure). This allows me to remove my downvote or change it to an upvote when (/if) a question is improved. I don't need to worry about whether anyone responds to any comments I may (or may not!) leave when downvoting. It allows me decide which questions I think will actually improve, but doesn't require me to manually recheck or to favorite a poor question.

Comment: This sounds similar to the changes to reopen q announced recently where closed questions that are improved by op are automatically added to the reopen Q. I'd like to see this.

Comment: I'd love to see this. Image the workflow: Down-vote -> comment -> OP edits the Q -> downvoter gets notification -> lift down-vote -> Profit: high quality content. :)

Comment: I'd love to see that, too! Though a window of 48h might be a bit small, considered some "posters" might not check back within this time frame (it might be argued for no time frame, or a different "upper limit", or making a time frame optional to be set "on demand"). However that "time frame" might be decided upon, I'd hail the feature!

Comment: related: [Notify question OP (and those who marked it a favourite) if an answer has been modified](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64692/146482)

Comment: very related: [Allow an edit to notify downvoters: “I think I've fixed the issue now - please check”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1751/146482), though I prefer your opt-in suggestion, or at least the [Or you could have a passive listing in your recent history area where you can see a recent list of edited questions of things you have "upvoted", "downvoted", "commented"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1758/146482)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To receive notifications for specific questions (including ones that you downvoted), please use the [follow post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/51) feature.

Answer (score 14):

I have added this feature to my [SOX (Stack Overflow Extras) userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/6091/26088) in version 1.0.3, currently in the DEV branch. You can easily install it from the linked Stack Apps post, where you can also enable a bunch of other optional features :)

It adds a small eye icon to all posts:

[image]

Clicking it will add the post to a watch list, and every time you browse an SE site, it looks for edits. If there is an edit, it will notify you:

[image]

You can choose to mark it as read, or if you don't click it, it will stay there for you to come back to it later.

I like the idea of only being notified within 48 hours, and I will be adding that to this script in the next few days.

You don't actually have to use this in conjunction with downvotes -- use it as an alternative 'favourite' feature for notifications on any edits (but not that I will be adding the 48 hour feature, stopping notifications after 2 days)

Answer (score 3):

This somehow reminds me of my [Notify close voters when a closed question gets edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56849/146482) request.

In either case, since an edit bumps a question, negative votes should simply be cancelled by other users' positive votes - which is one reason why it's good etiquette to not down-vote something that already has a score below -2 (unless the post is severely flawed beyond recovery): That way it has a chance to regain a positive voting score by just a few users.

That doesn't mean I disagree with your proposal, though. I actually like it, since there *are* cases where you "have" to down-vote an answer due to flaws (that you don't know how to solve) but spot potential for an excellent answer *if* someone manages to sort the issue out - and in that case you'd like to know about the possible fix. But unless you are the only one to spot this, there may already be a comment stating thos, and adding a "-1 for the same reason, please @tell me when you fix it" is meta-noise and the editor will probably not @notify everyone (or anyone) manually anyway.

So yes, this should be implemented in some way.

Comment: `good etiquette to not down-vote something that already has a score below -2` - Well, it is good etiquette, but I'd not be surprised to see many people downvote it further (crowd voting or bully voting).

Comment: @nhahtdh [Kick them while they are down](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/KickThemWhileTheyAreDown)

Comment: @nhahtdh I agree, crowd voting and bully voting is discouraging.