# Is it okay to not revoke a down-vote on an incorrect answer after it's been edited, after other correct answers have been posted?

Tags: discussion, edits, voting

Here's the situation: I visited a ~1 minute old question which no answers posted on it. I then submitted my (correct) answer to see that whilst I was answering an incorrect answer had been posted. (I guess this could fall under the [Fastest Gun in the West problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem), but I'm not sure if that applies when the answer isn't actually correct.)

As the answer was incorrect, I down-voted it and proceeded to re-read the question just to make sure I hadn't missed anything. By the time I'd finished the incorrect answer had been edited - this time it was correct, mentioning everything I'd mentioned in my own answer.

This all happened within 5 minutes of the incorrect answer being posted, so there is (unfortunately) no public-facing edit history for the originally incorrect answer.

In this situation, am I in the wrong if I leave the answer down-voted?

I'm asking this because in this situation I posted the correct answer first *but*, after editing, the originally incorrect answer is not only correct but also appears to have been answered correctly first - and thus will probably receive accepted answer status.

Comment: Simple answer: entirely up to you.

Comment: The only thing that're not really okay are revenge-voting and serial-voting. So, everything else goes, I guess?

Answer (score 3):

> In this situation, am I in the wrong if I leave the answer down-voted?

Yes. Downvotes should indicate a bad or wrong answer. If the poster fixed the answer, the downvotes should be redacted. It is a very similar mechanic to closing, once the question has been fixed it should be retracted.

Comment: I do wish I got notified of edits on answers I downvoted, so I could go back and reevaluate. Yes, there's the vote-list in my profile or favourites, but seriously. =)

Comment: So if I were to have posted a useless answer to this question before you posted this answer and you went on to down-vote it; then I edited it to say pretty much everything you said here, you'd feel obliged to revoke the down-vote?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: Yes, I'd do that. An answer which says the same as other answers should not be downvoted...but it should also not be upvoted.

Comment: @J.Steen: Well...it's more of a theoretical optimum, I think. ;)

Comment: @J.Steen that would be very useful, indeed. Some sort of personal addendum to the review queues, maybe?

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby Aye, very theoretical optimum, but I'd like the option. I care that much. It should be easier for me to care. =)

Comment: @Monolo Considering you'd want to review them in that case, that'd be logical, yeah. =)

Comment: @J.Steen Sounds like a good candidate for a feature request to me...

Comment: @Monolo I can find numerous such requests already asked, so mine would be closed as duplicate. [This is the earliest I can find](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68106/notify-me-of-edits-to-posts-ive-voted-on) =)

Comment: @J.Steen Yes, but times have changed. And since votes (downvotes probably more than up votes) affect a person's perception of the place deeply, I think it is only fair to get an opportunity to re-think a downvote after a fellow user has attempted to improve on a post. A one-click action of love, if you will.

Comment: @Monolo Oh, I agree. I just know a proposition like that will be closed as duplicate, with comments to put a bounty on the original. And it's likely to be status-declined anyway, due to the developer effort involved, et c, et c. =(