# How can I track other comments to an answer which I commented?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notify user when their name is mentioned in comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2035/notify-user-when-their-name-is-mentioned-in-comment)

I couldn't find a way to do this and manually doing this is not fun.

Basically in stackoverflow how can I keep track of other comments to an answer/question which I commented?

I'm generally interested in most of the other comments or the comments directly to me in under that answer/question.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2035/suggestion-notify-user-when-their-name-is-mentioned-in-comment

Comment: Also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have

Comment: @Ivo: In which sense is this [meta-tag:status-completed]? Maybe you want to add an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible, particularly if the question or answer where you've put a comment in is not yours.

The Manual Way: Click on your username between the envelope and the reputation, and then click on Recent tab. Thread titles where you have comments are highlighted in blue.

Comment: fair enough. I'll do feature request or vote if it exists.