# Please add comment formatting to the user's recent activity page to match normal comment formatting

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, stack-exchange, recent-activity

Supporting bold/italic/code formatting and autolinking in comments has been great. However, it's ironic that this doesn't happen when the comment is displayed on your recent activity page. You can't navigate to a particular link directly in your `/users/recent/{user-id}` page. It should be a straightforward thing to add.

Comment: Could you try rephrasing this?  I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Pesto: really? Go to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/recent/23921 and see this comment there. You'll see that this is **not bold**, *not italic* and no links are there.

Comment: @Mehrdad: replies to comments don't appear there, unfortunately. You'll have to post a comment on one of Pesto's posts for him to see it.

Comment: @Kyle: I think I remember they did appear sometime. Is the behavior changed or I'm wrong?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Afraid not, but it is a popular feature request http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's worse than that - if they contain a `<` then they get broken altogether.

The comment from Josh on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085051/problem-with-printing-contents-of-a-list/1085059#1085059) (I'm happily married by the way, Josh, bad luck but I'm flattered all the same) appears as "I" in my envelope page.

Answer (score 0):

If I look at your recent comments on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/33708?tab=recent#sort-top, it looks good to me. Your 'recent' page (accessible by clicking the envelope button) is not the same view. If the formatting isn't visible there, that might be something to look in to!

Comment: He is talking about the 'envelope' page, and I can confirm that formatting does not appear there

Comment: the "envelope" page? I was wondering what should I call it.

Comment: Fair enough! Note that the 'envelope' page is only viewable by -you-, also...not that that makes the lack of formatting excusable, but it does make it difficult for me to see the link :)

Comment: @Andy: Unacceptable excuse. It's like saying, hey, you are the CEO and only you can see this crap report so it doesn't matter. It's actually worse than that: Hey users, this profile management screen can only be seen by **you** so we didn't bother to fix it. This **you** is every user on this site.

Comment: Oh, I agree! I just wanted to point out that it's odd that it's broken **there**, and not every other place comments are visible, which wasn't clear in your original post :)