# Add a [reply to comment] feature

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Reply to comment feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11098/reply-to-comment-feature-request)
>   [Let’s make it easier to reply within comments!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4798/lets-make-it-easier-to-reply-within-comments)

I would like a **reply to comment** feature to SO, so when someone replies to one of your comments, it will be shown on the summary page.

The reasons are:

- important information or comments may be lost if you don't manually check all the threads you've commented to.
- there's almost no way to see the newest replies to old comments, especially if you ask something in the comments.
- Comments are usually the way someone notifies you of things that have changed, sometimes those replies are directed at comments not at answers, and comments are frequently used to complete existing answers without creating new ones.

Comment: Who's the first to find a dupe?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4798/lets-make-it-easier-to-reply-within-comments

Comment: Or this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11098/reply-to-comment-feature-request

Comment: @135200 It was your second dupe that was the first that came to mind/find.

Comment: @9314 There's probably more where that came from :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you only get notified of comments when you own the post.

You will now get notified of any comments that refer to you by **@username** in a comment, even if you do not own the post.

Rules:

1. Only applies to other people in the comments that you are commenting on.
2. **Response must include @username that you are referring to**, where "username" is a reasonable match to the user's current display name (as seen in the comments above yours).
3. There must be a starts-with, case insensitive match of at least THREE characters to the displayname. So @a and @ab will never match anyone or anything.
4. Spaces cannot be used to match, so if the person's display name is "Peter Smith" then just use @peter to match.
5. Matching is performed in reverse chronological order, so if there are five people named "John" in the comments, writing "hey @john, have you considered apples?" will match the *most recent* John to comment.