# Disallow usernames that cannot be @replied to

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comment-replies, display-names

Take e.g. the username [t..](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/467/t). Maybe they do it on purpose, but the @reply-system is there for a good reason.

Comment: The reply-system should work for this user shouldn't it?  I thought you had to have at least 3 characters for the reply system to work.

Comment: what about when the user name comes form the openId provider?

Comment: @Ian Ringrose: That is [no longer used](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64439/my-profile-just-went-blank/64542#64542).

Comment: Dots and dashes [are valid](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51911/the-dot-in-username-within-first-3-character-preventing-from-comment-replies), so you're right @Barry.

Comment: `status-completed` as per [Prevent (or at least notify about) display names shorter than 3 chars](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45241/prevent-or-at-least-notify-about-display-names-shorter-than-3-chars/50693#50693).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to my comment above, which I can no longer edit, see Jeff's answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11098/reply-to-comment-feature-request).  He states that *case insensitive match of at least THREE characters* for the reply to work. So as this users name is 3 chars it should work fine.

Comment: so it also works with punctuation characters? I somehow got the idea that only letters and numbers would work... but then again, I didn't test but assumed

Comment: @Tobias, single quotes, dots and dashes [are valid](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51911/the-dot-in-username-within-first-3-character-preventing-from-comment-replies), along with word characters (letters, digits, underscores): `[\w'\.\-]`

Comment: @Arjan: thanks, I didn't know that, somehow I thought only alphanumerics would work

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to be able to use `@name` to reply to their comment.  Even if the name is too short (can you do that?) you just quote what you can.  If the user doesn't get the notice that you've made a comment about their comment, that is their problem.  Now, if you are really asking for a mechanism to be able to contact a person reliably, then that is another issue - rather independent of the being able to respond to them via comments (which is just a convenient trick in the absence of separate communication). It has been requested before (back in the days before MSO, let alone since). I still support that request - but then people who want to contact me can by looking at my profile.  I can understand some people not wanting to be bothered by people contacting them out of the blue; so far, I've not had anyone abusing my contact information.  And I'd ignore abuse - or point out that it is abuse the first time and ignore it thereafter.  Of course, Gmail makes that easy if I need it.