# Stack Exchange chat name mention inbox confusion

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat, global-inbox

I checked my Stack Exchange Inbox (drop down list) just now and it mentioned three messages for me. Two were legit - the last was [this one](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/210158#210158) on **The Tavern** which was another Mark.

Comment: Let's put it this way: If you're at a party, and someone yells "Hey Mark!", you'd turn around. That's the principle chat replies are modeled after.

Comment: @balpha - I'm surprised it is implemented that way but you've made a great analogy - thanks.

Comment: Did somebody call me?

Comment: @Marc C - you too? This question is becoming a @Mark / @Marc convention...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That follows the standard rules of @blah conflicts, I'm afraid. You would also have got a highlight inside chat for that.

That was a reply; if they had *just* used the explicit reply (rather than adding the @Mark), it would have known who it meant, but that @Mark was ambiguous so all the "Mark*" who had been active in the room were included.

*Usually*, auto-complete on the name would have given a less ambiguous match... but they are just "Mark".

<strike>You'd get the same problem if you'd both been talking in comments on SOFU.</strike> I don't propose there is much we can do about it.

Comment: *You'd get the same problem if you'd both been talking in comments* - I thought that only the [most-recent matched commenter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11098/35918#35918) gets notified, or is that wrong?

Comment: @Tim - hmmm... it seems you are correct. But I think balpha hits the nail on the head with his comment above.

Comment: @Marc - thanks. So I guess that, if multiple Marcs (with a C) had contributed to *this page* they'd all get *this post* in their inbox, right?

Comment: @Marc: Yeah, that makes sense, especially given the more fluid nature of the chat. :) The only counterpoint I might make in this case is that the OP's lack of activity in that room (it seems he has no posts/hasn't been in chat for at least 18 days?) makes him unlikely enough of a candidate that he doesn't need a system-wide notification. At the same time though, it's impossible to know for sure, so I suppose it's a better safe than sorry sort of situation.

Comment: @Tim - 18 days? Hmmm... I suspect that should probably indeed rule them out. Let me try to tweak that...

Comment: @Mark - no, time corrected me; in comments it is only the most recent; I'm changing chat to only look at people who've been in the room in the last week - seem like a fair compromise?

Comment: @Marc - sounds great. I don't know if **one week** is the appropriate time interval - I'll trust you have a better idea of that. Thanks.

Comment: @marc one week seems like an absurdly large window for name mentions. Two days seems more sane to me..

Comment: @Jeff - will reduce

Comment: @Marc, if there's only 1 match, are you going to ignore the time window?  Thinking about chats that have less activity.  ALso, what if the 2 days eliminates all matches?

Comment: I think it is _way_ too sensitive.  I have never really participated in the chat yet.  I poke the rooms every once in a while just to see what it's all about.  I haven't viewed the meta chat rooms for a while now (over a week or so) and I received a notification for a message clearly directed to Mr. [@Atwood](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/263836#263836).  If reducing the window is not an option, it should at least be only for people who have actually participated within this time.

Comment: @JeffM - I can see exactly 1 instance of this looking at Oct/Nov: [this one](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=263836#263836) - but I will investigate. Fortunately, it logs *everything*...

Comment: @Marc: Ok thanks.  I just thought it was odd to get notified for it when I never really participated.

Comment: @JeffM - in this case, since it wasn't an *exact* match, there is a 2-day limit. You entered that room "2010-11-03 06:57:34.093", that reply was "2010-11-05 05:27:18.807", which is within 2 days. I see you have some matches in September too, but that pre-dates the changes. So in short, *since we changed the rules*, there has been only 1 false positive, and that from a room that you *had visited recently*... You might disagree, but to me it sounds like it is working fine...?

Comment: @JeffM - the problem with "participated" in that context, is that it is very common to "Oh, heya @fred - while you're there, have you [blah]" - when @fred has *entered* but not *spoken*...

Comment: @Marc: To be honest, I really don't remember visiting any particular room in meta.  I remember following a link provided by another user in a comment somewhere, just don't recall how recent that happened.  2 days sounds reasonable, I thought it was 1 week until I saw the comment.

Comment: @Marc: Maybe this deserves its own request, but would it be possible to not receive these messages until we actually talk in the chat room at least once?  Maybe per channel or any channel?  Maybe something we can opt out of?  Or perhaps having to opt in, being reminded on the first message sent in chat.  I think it would be weird for someone who's in a similar position (though highly uncommon), peeks at the chat rooms, and sees the message thinking, "I never said anything to have received that message" having no intention to chat.

Comment: @JeffM - I think that it would be acceptable to not include @mentions until they have said something in the room - they'll still see the on-screen highlighting greeting them, anyways.

Comment: @JeffM - that is now *in*, by the way. See, we do listen ;p