# Chat: Partial Ping Inaccuracy

Tags: support, stack-exchange, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Getting Marc's chat notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73931/getting-marcs-chat-notifications)

This has been a problem I've noticed over the past few weeks since a user named "Matt" started participating in the [JavaScript](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) chat room on StackOverflow.

Since then, I've received countless pings via partial matching. Today, I signed on to find **12** new pings, none of which directed at me, all taking place in chat room(s) I was not inside of. This is quite bothersome and needs to be remedied.

Partial matching is nice for certain occasions, but should only be applicable when user X is actually inside of the chat room.

Even then, I'd still get pinged if a user named "Matt" was in the room at the same time. I'm not sure how one would solve that problem, save for a ping feature with precise intent.

Comment: Apologies if this is a duplicate. I couldn't find anything via the search about it.

Comment: Were you recently in the rooms?  Pings work for a couple days or something after you've been in a room.

Comment: @MatthewRead It appears one of the rooms was created with messages migrated from the JavaScript room, so they would all have originated from the JavaScript room.

Comment: Long story short: This will stop two days after you've been in the room last.