# Avoid pinging multiple users in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, notifications, ping

Several chat room users are becoming annoyed by a certain feature of the chat room notification system. When there are two people in a chat room, say `John` and `JohnSmith`, and someone pings `@John`, `JohnSmith` is also pinged. This is naturally annoying to `JohnSmith`, especially if someone is having a long discussion with `John`.

I propose a new feature, where only `John` would be pinged when someone types `@John`.

The basic rules for a @ping would be

- If it is a reply to a previous message, ping the user that posted it (as I believe it does now).
- If it is an exact match to one user, ping only that user.
- If it is an exact match to more than one user, ping only those users.
- If there is no exact match, ping all users starting with that name (as it does now).

If possible, it would be nice an if exact match would include case-sensitivity, but I don't think it matters much if that isn't possible.

Comment: A [similar question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73931/183013) has been asked before. However, it seems that we still have a problem. I would like if anyone who has experienced this issue could share more details. I don't know the exact details, since I haven't seen another Kendall in chat.

Comment: See: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/938/what-are-the-rules-for-when-chat-messages-appear-in-a-users-inbox/939#939

Comment: @KyleTrauberman: Thanks for the link. I think that means this question only applies to cases where both people have the same first name, as in `John` and `JohnSmith`.

Comment: Ah, yes.  The "Rob" and "Michael" problem.  (`@RobertHarvey` `@RobertCartaino,` `@MichaelMyers` `@MichaelMrozek`).

Comment: it does seem that if there's an exact match, the ping should be *just* to the exact match.

Comment: @JeffAtwood: I'm not sure exactly what happens. It could be that the ping *sound* doesn't play, but I know there is a notification of some sort to `JohnSmith`.

Comment: @KendallFrey: Cant upvote this question as i dont have 15 rep but thanks for posting this + hopefully a solution is found.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is already partially implemented.

If the ping phrase is an exact match to the full name or one of the words in the name, a ping won't be issued (A ping highlight next to the name however will [image: will])

So for example, if we have *Mad Scientist* and *Madara Uchiha* in the same room, when someone pings @Mad, only *Mad Scientist will be pinged*.

Still, when a full match is found on both users (either by name or by word), both will be pinged.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have been fixed.

Some of us did a bit of experimenting.

I first changed my username to `Madishearth`. In the room, at the time, were two more users, [Madara Uchicha](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/25454/madara-uchiha) and [Mad Scientist](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/180/mad-scientist)

While `@Mad` got pink highlighting for all three users, it only pinged Mad Scientist, regardless of who had last posted.

Then, I changed my username to `Madashearth`. The `@Mad` ping worked the same way. A `@Mada` ping pinged both me and Madara Uchicha, and gave both of us purple highlighting.

Then, I changed my username to `Madara Uchiha2`. `@MadaraUchiha` pinged the "real" Madara only, and not me. I still saw the purple highlighting.

---

> - If it is a reply to a previous message, ping the user that posted it (as I believe it does now).

Check. Always worked.

> - If it is an exact match to one user, ping only that user.

Check. See `@MadaraUchiha`

> If it is an exact match to more than one user, ping only those users.

Not sure, but combining the results from `@Mada` and `@Madara`, I'd say that this works :)

> If there is no exact match, ping all users starting with that name (as it does now).

Check. Always worked.

The only difference is that if there is a *word match* (`Mad Scientist` vs `MadScientist` for `@Mad`), it only pings the user, who has a first "name" matching with the ping text. To me, that's a feature, not a bug :)

Comment: I just got a flashback from the time of @tim...

Comment: We're all mad here...