# How do I ping the right bob?

Tags: feature-request, support, chat, ping

[image]

We have two bobs at the moment. Bob (with the fox avatar) is a long time user, and bob, with the green avatar.

I'd like to ping Bob, without bothering bob with my pings. I see two ways to do this - It's trivial for me to get the username - so could we have a way to ping a user by user id number, the same way I'd do a superping as a mod? Alternatively, is there some way (case sensitivity? Letting me click on a user?) where I can pick one of the bobs?

For the moment I'm replying to the appropriate (B|b)ob but this might get messy if I wanted to actually initiate a conversation.

Comment: [Not yet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268351/rfc-better-chat-mentions-a-prototype).

Comment: It looks like implenting ping by user id would be the easiest way, you can just hover over a user and look at the id in the link. Maybe there should also be a ping icon as well (like the flag/star/link icons, just beside the user). Also, ping by id would probably need a new symbol. (@#<id> or something?)

Comment: Perhaps you could set up a global Bob numbering server. Each Bob could apply for a Bob number and then we'd refer to each one by their global Bob number. We'd all agree to ignore all Bobs without a global Bob number to force them to apply for one.

Comment: There's a LOT of Bobs. The bob I wanted to ping didn't even turn up in the superping menu

Comment: [ping Tim instead](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132562/165773)

Comment: In that case, How do I ping the right Tim?

Comment: Do they not *both* get pinged? If you ping an `@Oli` in a room with an `@oliver` and an `@olive`, [all three get pinged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234029). It's been a while since I reported that and a while since all my pings chased out our last `@oliver`, but I think that's still the case.

Comment: I seem to recall it pinged both. The less senior bob changed his name. That's not a good solution though.