# Multiple names means multiple notifications

Tags: feature-request, chat, notifications, ping

When people chat in chat rooms, with the same name, our inboxes get full. It can also happen if 2 people with the same name reply to the same post (I think) but appreciate this is not common. My user name is Dave, and this is common here (as well as posts like [How do I ping the right bob?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274364/how-do-i-ping-the-right-bob))

This has been discussed many times on the SE sites.

For example, my inbox

[image]

The Dave in question (shown by question mark) is https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/171610/dave

Can we have an option within our profile to turn on / off chat room notifications (so that they don't appear in the notification box) but still appear by our icon beside the text box (within chat)

Comment: I'm not exactly a socialite, but I've *never* had this problem.  How do you keep up in any case?  If you're getting that many messages, do you really need notifications?  Or are you just not checking your inbox often enough?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I've shown a screen shot. As you can see, there is another "Dave" on the SU sites and is in chat. When I log on I see **his** notifications

Comment: Oh, I see.  Hrm, well the answer to that problem is to use proper ID's in the software, rather than trying to name-match.  Or, y'know, give yourself a more unique user name.  Perhaps "GuitarDave"?

Comment: Other Dave already suggested same feature. Great Daves think alike! :D

Comment: Just wanted to say that after speaking with @Dave this morning. I recently changed my name to help resolve this issue, not sure how long it takes for my name change to propogate though. Doing this is a hopeful temporary bandaid to the situation but the issue still persists.

Comment: Added note  This is also a potential vulnerability related to privacy / evesdropping where users are able to easily monitor others actions to know if people are logged on the network and gives the user a front row seat of monitoring