# Make user unpingable in chat

Tags: support, chat, ping

In our chat room, there is a regular (and RO) named Tom.  Recently, another user named Tom came into the room.  He didn't say much; not much was said to him; and now he's gone.  The problem is that he is now in the list of pingable people, so he gets notified of every message that we send to the Tom who is here all the time.

Is there a way to remove the other Tom from the list of pingable people?

Comment: Request for chat update.  There is More info than just his username so,  they should have a way to accomplish thus :)

Comment: There's no explicit way right now, no, short of either of them changing their display name. Once the other Tom leaves the room (I believe it takes a few days to fully be considered "gone", if memory serves), he'll stop getting pinged as well.

Comment: Are you sure the username was Tom and not [Tim](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132562/158100)?

Comment: @AdamLear it is [seven days](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5262658#5262658)

Comment: You might want to support [RFC: Better chat @mentions – A prototype](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268351/rfc-better-chat-mentions-a-prototype).

Comment: Until then, just reply to specific messages (using the chat's inbuilt reply UI) rather than users generally. That should reply only to that specific user.

Comment: Is the new Tom complaining about getting pinged?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234029/disable-three-letter-pings-from-chat-to-save-oliver-olivier-and-olive-from-oli

Comment: @Catija: Not yet, but at least one of us (me) is using "@Tom" less so that we don't annoy him.  I'd rather not have that limitation.

Comment: @Catija I am one of the Tom(s). I was thinking about asking this question but it looks like zondo opened it for me. I have found this kind of annoying. I'm not one to complain but whenever someone pings the other Tom, I get pinged when I'm in the chatroom or from my phone if I'm not. It would be nice it there was a way to target specific users of the same username inside chatrooms as this would no longer be an issue for me and those with duplicate usernames elsewhere.

Comment: @Tom there is... You just have to do what Christian said above and use replies.

Comment: @Catija Sure, but how do I tell (enforce) other users to do this?

Comment: @Tom: A pinned message.  I just did it.

Comment: @zondo Alright, we'll see if that works, thanks