# Chat ping "bug"?

Tags: bug, chat, notifications, ping

So after chatting for a while in some SO chats, we encounterd a little problem which could get very annoying in long conversations where 2 people would have similar names.

`sami` & `sam` would both be pinged if I would be talking to `sam`

Is there a posibility to fix this issue since I really don't find any good reasoning for this to be a chat function.

There is a reason that we can `tab` to select the person we want to ping, so why would we want to ping everyone having the same combination of letters in their name?

These are just suggestions, but if this is a bad statement would anyone be willing to explain to me why this functionality was chosen for.

Not addressing this issue causes people like me to uninstal SE app, and not use mail notifications just because of all the pings we get.

Comment: And related if not dupe: [Disable three-letter pings from chat to save Oliver, Olivier and Olive from Oli's pings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234029/287976)

Comment: [*name change to "Tim something".*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132562/158100)

Comment: Not a bug. There was lots of [work done to address this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263978/rfc-better-chat-mentions), but it got nuked at some point when SE ran out of resources for that. I'm pretty sure they'll not resume this in the near future. (6-8 years.)

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard I have actually seen those posts and was questioning whether I should ask the question or not, because there is still no real fix for this and its generally really annoying for similiar names shared amongst people

Comment: Agree it can be annoying, agree it's annoying they didn't fix/change this, but that's just how things are. Asking again won't make them work any faster, I'm afraid.