# Remove shortened name chat pinging

Tags: feature-request, chat, ping

**This is a not duplicate; I am asking that this "feature" be removed.**

*This Q now has more votes than [the previous request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234029/disable-three-letter-pings-from-chat-to-save-oliver-olivier-and-olive-from-oli?lq=1), thus making this one more valuable.*

---

Pinging the name `@nick`, in chat, also pings all users whose names start with "nick" (like my own).

*Not only do I get pings while in the chatroom, I also receive notifications on my phone about new pings.*

[image]

In the case of "nick", and room 17 (Javascript), 3 users will get pinged:

- nick
- NickAlexeev
- NickDugger (me)

[image]

There are other cases of this happening as well, and sometimes with names not as common as above.

The importance of this feature was before there was auto-completion, which even mobile now has: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGnVi.png

Typing in the first few letters and using autocompletion will spell out their full username. This should be encouraged, and this short-name matching should be removed.

---

tldr; Pinging users with a shortened version of their name causes irritation and should be removed.

Comment: For people with a long name, Tab-completion already works fine so I don't really see why the short name form would be needed at all.

Comment: Agreed, this was much more useful before tab complete on mobile. now I see very little use case for it.

Comment: I must admit Ill miss pinging multiple people at one time, however definitely agree this needs fixing.

Comment: No matter how you put it, it's not a bug. That's how it was supposed to work, so asking to change it is feature request.

Comment: Very well, It's a feature request. Request still stands, though.

Comment: Also not 100% sure what exactly you suggest, can you please clarify?

Comment: It's very clear that I want the feature removed where you can ping someone by using the first few letters of their username.

Comment: +1, there's a Stephan in the Python room that I get a bunch of pings for regularly

Comment: At the very least, I think this feature should be disabled when someone isn't in the chat room, even if they were there recently.

Comment: Is there some subtlety here that I'm missing? I would assume that there's a not insignificant number of Mikes that I would also be receiving pings for but that's not the case - do you have to be active in the room?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Yeah, the same ping rules apply. I just happen to frequent one of the most active rooms, so we get more people joining.

Comment: Have you considered user scripting this feature out in the mean time? I mean, you guys are the JavaScript room after all.

Comment: @TravisJ I have not, and if I'm being honest, I probably won't. -- This also won't help with the notifications I'm getting on my phone.

Comment: Related, not duplicate though in my opinion because the issue was seen as resolved at that time. [Avoid pinging multiple users in chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136292/178816)

Comment: @NickDugger - That is true, the phone notifications are probably issued server side through the notification queue.

Comment: @random Not a duplicate, because the other question was not solved. Until either this one or your linked one is accepted or denied, I suggest keeping the focus here, since It's newer and has more votes.

Comment: That's not how duplicates work. The other question is better written

Comment: @random Duplicates need to have an answer in order to be a duplicate; neither are solved.

Comment: It's a feature request. If the other request had an answer you wouldn't even be making a feature request for something that has already been solved.

Comment: @random But it doesn't have an answer, making your point ridiculous. From the help docs: "The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place."

Comment: If neither has an answer, there are no answers to "[get] in one place"

Comment: You are asking for the same thing the other feature request is asking for. That makes this post an exact duplicate. If there is a queue of 12 people asking for a hamburger with the lot, but no mayo, then those are all duplicates. Even if the place is only selling watermelon and all the people in line are still waiting

Comment: @random The docs **clearly** state the purpose of marking as a duplicate; your suggestion does not match that case; your argument is invalid.

Comment: You need to read more than one page on the site http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225852/why-can-a-feature-request-or-bug-report-without-an-answer-be-used-as-a-duplicate

Comment: So, a duplicate on Meta is different from a duplicate on any other SE site? They might want to put that somewhere in the help docs.

Comment: @NickDugger yes, duplicate on meta means that they're duplicate, not that it solves the issue. You've asked a feature request that has been asked before. The questions are duplicates.

Comment: @Tim according tot he link posted by random, the more upvoted request is viewed as 'more valuable' and therefore should trump the other request. Albeit this is a meta answer and not a hard rule.

Comment: If we're going on hard rules anyways, then mine should still stay open (see help docs). So one way or another, closing as a dupe should be reversed.

Comment: @rlemon hmm fair point. But this is a duplicate, and the other one has no close votes atm.

Comment: "*This Q now has more votes than the previous request, thus making this one more valuable*" But all your "valuable" votes here could have been on the other question which *already has* 14 votes. Then the total net upvotes for your "cause" would have been greater, and you more likely to have gained some official attention. A bounty would have been better on the other question really.

Comment: @Tim this one has close votes for *appearing* to qualify as a duplicate. According to official help docs, it is not. According to the Q linked from random, it now is not. Either way, it currently is not a duplicate, due to the value it now brings.

Comment: @Tim the argument could be made the other is a duplicate of this. [on meta the age is meaningless](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165852/duplicate-question-changes-cant-mark-duplicates-by-same-user/165854#comment484888_165854)

Comment: @NickDugger no, it's still a duplicate. Maybe it shouldn't be *closed* as one. I think the other one is better, and so I closed it as such. I'm flagging for a mod to decide.

Comment: The link explaining why feature requests don't need an answer doesn't say to split the argument over a dozen requests, but to focus it on one. And clarity of the request trumps whatever votes it scores. Which is why this is the sub

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need much more clarity than "remove X feature" -- and I have edited the Question to be more understandable. Regardless, it still does not fit the definition of an SE duplicate from the help docs, or the linked Q

Comment: both questions are clear on their intent; "remove the partial username match pings". I don't know why this is such an argument. the end goal of a feature request is to get a [meta-tag:status-complete]. If this question is gaining traction let it stay open and close the older one.

Comment: It's gaining traction from being bumped by all the meta commentary being edited into the question @rle

Comment: You guys are being excessively nit-picky; The two sources that have been linked to as authoritative text (help docs, and the meta Q) both do not qualify this Q as a duplicate. It was a duplicate until this one gained more value, which it has. I'm sorry for not seeing the other one earlier, but lessons learned, and we move on.

Comment: [The UI could have some work done to it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189782/meta-duplicates-dont-require-an-answer-dont-suggest-there-is-one-when-thats), but [on meta, to close as a dupe, the other question doesn't need an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169388/why-can-we-flag-vote-a-question-on-meta-as-duplicate-of-another-question-which-h). We have bounties to attract attention. This isn't meant to be nit-picky, it's to consolidate bugs and feature requests (we don't really need 100 questions open asking for the same feature).