# How to ping users with the same display name in chat and in comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, chat, comment-replies, ping

## Notion

To simplify writing, I'll simply refer "users with same profile display name (case *insensitive*) [user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?page=1&tab=reputation&filter=all&search=user)" as "users" (*with* quotes), and an arbitrarily user picked from "users" as "user" (*with* quotes).

## Problem

Suppose that *multiple* "users" participate in the *same* chat room and/or comment thread.  How can one effectively ping a specific "user"?

## My attempt

From the accepted answer in [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/259305), matching of "user" from "users" is done by *reverse* chronological order.  It suggests typing out full names *without* spaces to differentiate.  However, that *doesn't* work for "users".  There's no way to [Avoid pinging multiple users in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136292/259305).

Comment: Related/If not possible duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125994/how-to-reply-to-one-user-among-two-having-same-names?rq=1