# Please can I disable pings from rooms I'm no longer in?

Tags: feature-request, chat, ping

I've read [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139151/chat-gives-me-notifications-intended-for-other-user), so I know why I'm getting pings from the Maths room: I went there.

I was there for a few minutes and then I left, and now I'm getting a bunch of pings because someone else called Matt goes there and people like him.

I'd really like a button I can push to silence pings from certain rooms. I don't chat in the maths room normally, so I'm not missing anything.

[image: Matt in Maths]

Comment: His user name probably isn't `Matt`, is it? Someone else is simply not completing it? Otherwise, he'd be a better match and you wouldn't get the notification.

Comment: It is Matt, I'll pop in a screen grab

Comment: I'm probably not getting pings for direct replies, but I'm certainly getting pings from the other things

Comment: It'll go away eventually if you've left the room. I have no idea how long it takes though; I accidentally popped into an SO chat with another Ben and stopped getting pings within the day but I think that's because I never talked in the room

Comment: I'll wait and see, then @BenBrocka, it is probably a little under a day since I was last in there. A button to hasten the process would be a great addition :)

Comment: So glad there isn't another Yannis around ;)