# Pinging inconsistencies in chat

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat, ping

So today we came across an issue with the pinging system in chat; when a user has a shorter version of another user's name (i.e. "Ben" and "Benjamin" was the case we found), if the other user has a comment *after* the first user, it pings the wrong person.

[image: "@Ben" pinged "Benjamin" instead]

I realise this may not be a "[bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/234170/3073006)" as such, just an unexpected feature. Should something be done about this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Both Ben's should get a ping in such case. (chat pings are different from comment replies)

Comment: @ShadowWizard unfortunately in this case I didn't for some reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. See [this answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/938/what-are-the-rules-for-when-chat-messages-appear-in-a-users-inbox/939#939) for the details; "@Ben" will only match a user called "Benjamin" if there is no other user who is more likely to be addressed as "@Ben", which means either "Ben" or something like "Ben Foo Bar".

You say

> it pings the wrong person.

but that's not really true – if "@Ben" pings a user called "Ben", that is hardly unexpected.

You *could* argue that it should ping *both* Ben and Benjamin, but not doing that was the compromise to fix [over-pinging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73931/getting-marcs-chat-notifications).