# I get notifications when someone with my name is @ replied to in chat

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat, notifications

Here's a screen shot of what causes the notification:
[image]

Is this a known issue? Anything I can do to stop it?

Comment: Do you get notifications, or just highlights?  The system tries to help you find references to yourself, and just highlights if you have a partial match that's not good enough for a notification.  You didn't show your Gravatar at the lower left, if you have a real notification there will be a number in red.

Answer (score 9):

Quoting my comment from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66290/stack-exchange-chat-name-mention-inbox-confusion#comment-158699) (just replace "Mark" with "Matt"):

> Let's put it this way: If you're at a party, and someone yells "Hey Mark!", you'd turn around. That's the principle chat replies are modeled after.

I see your confusion with the *first* "@Matt" in your screenshot. That's just the orange highlighting, though; you did not get a notification for that (it was a direct reply to a message by the other Mark). May be worth to improve that highlighting logic.

As for the second one – well, they said "@Matt" (and didn't use a direct reply), and you are a user named "Matt" who was (either at that very time, or at least recently) in the room. Hence you were notified (just like the other Matt was).

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73931/getting-marcs-chat-notifications/74950#74950) for the precise rules as to when a user gets a notification for a @mention of their name.

Comment: I get red notifications in my inbox in the left hand where the stack exchange drop down menu is, not just highlighting

Comment: Are you sure you received an inbox notifiation for the message starting with "Well, unfortunately, the answer is ..."?

Comment: All I know is I log on and have a notification, I click on the notification and it brings up that conversation.

Comment: Yes, the line that's highlighted in yello -- that's what I refer to as "the second one".