# Mega-super-duper-duper delayed chat notification

Tags: bug, chat, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Getting Marc's chat notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73931/getting-marcs-chat-notifications)

So I haven't been in chat for [4 days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMRBG.png) (and that was the first time in a blue moon, for ~10 mins to see what the cool kids do these days), yet I've just been [poked by a notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt9Vk.png) from an ["@" reply that got sent tonight at 23:03](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2561291#2561291).

Whilst I'm humbled that the system [chose to thank me and all that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt9Vk.png), I find it a bit weird (cough, [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)), that the system chose to notify me when there is another [user called Matt](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/342129/matt-mcdonald) who;

- was in the chat room at the time
- had sent a message < 1 minute before the "@" notification was sent

Whether this is a [problem with "Matt" being such a common name and the system having a seizure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111237/i-get-notifications-when-someone-with-my-name-is-replied-to-in-chat) remains to be seen...

Comment: Your name is better match for `@Matt` than *Matt McDonald*. The other user just didn't care what the autocompletion could have told him: That there were two Matts and he's replying to the wrong one. What's the problem again?

Comment: @Daniel Replying to *both*. Chat (unlike comments) can generate several pings per mention.

Comment: @balpha: I'd understand the mention if there were multiple possible matches in the room *at the same time*, but the fact I got notified of a `@` when I was *last in the room 4 days ago* seemed strange. Is there not a cut-off where the system thinks "nah, he can't be meaning you..."?

Comment: Yes, it's seven days. The most elaborate description of the precise rules is at http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/938/what-are-the-rules-for-when-chat-messages-appear-in-a-users-inbox (also linked to in http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74950/115866)