# What exactly does the activity in the profile display?

Tags: support, profile-page

Does the activity tell me if someone has replied to a comment I leave in an answer?

i.e. I comment on a question or answer, maybe asking for clarification or something.  Will my activity be updated if someone replies to the **comment**?

Or is it just a stream of all my questions, answers and comments?

Comment: see also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4798/lets-make-it-easier-to-reply-within-comments

Answer (score 2):

> Does the activity tell me if someone has replied to a comment I leave in an answer?

No, It only displays your activity aka "stream of all my questions, answers and comments".

Also, as pointed out by belgariontheking:

> Additionally, any time someone edits or receives a badge. – Michael Bay's belgariontheking

Comment reply's are not a part of any notification to the intended "@username".  The OP of the question/answer will be notified though of a comment to thier question/answer.

Comment: Additionally, any time someone edits or receives a badge.

Comment: You can only see comment replies if they happen to come on things that you yourself asked or answered.

Comment: It sure would be nice if I were notified of all comments starting with "@<myname>". It would make it a lot easier to pick up on responses to comments I have left.

Answer (score 1):

No, replies to comments are not listed.
Yes, the other stuff is listed.