# Do StackExchange network site allow users to change their display name?

Tags: support, profile-page, display-names

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should you be allowed to change your handle in SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29196/should-you-be-allowed-to-change-your-handle-in-so)
>   [I changed my oldname to currentname … now the @me comments point nowhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77546/i-changed-my-oldname-to-currentname-now-the-me-comments-point-nowhere)

Do StackExchange network sites allow users to change their display name? Because in question discussions the display name is referred to by other users in comments. If the user changes his/her display name, the comments will not be clear.

Comment: You can change your display name on every 30 day's interval only.

Comment: @Lucifer there is a workaround for that if user has account on a different site ([described here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45200/add-warning-when-changing-display-name)). I tested this workaround about a month ago - worked like a charm :)

Comment: Yes you can change it - on every site in your user profile page you have "edit" link. Click it and in the edit profile page you can change the display name then save the changes. As for comments mess, see linked duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

Yes; you are allowed to change your display name every so often (about once a month).

Yes; if you change your name, comments are not edited to suit your new name.

Suggestion: Don't change your name very often if you're worried about comments no longer applying clearly.