# What counts as a ping?

Tags: support, comments, mobile-web, comment-replies

On desktop SE, I can type `@` and the usernames that I can ping will be suggested.
It's known that pinging the OP as the only commenter, or pinging the author of an answer as the only commenter, will strip the `@ping`.

On mobile SE, it is not really possible to ping a user in comments, which is very annoying to me since I way prefer the mobile site over the mobile app.

However, a few times in the past few days I have tried to ping a commenter from the mobile site, just by typing their name. For instance, if the user's name is `RikerW`, I typed `@rikerw blah blah`.

Those pings didn't get replies from active users. We also know that `@ping`s are just text, not special entities like on Facebook, which is why they are not updated with usernames. (see [Change all @username references in comments when a user changes their name?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31851/310919))

What causes a ping? [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/310919) says "reasonable match", but what is that?

- Must I type the `@` and select one of the options with `TAB`, or
- can I just type the user's name?
- Does case matter?
- Is it possible to ping from the mobile site?

Comment: Mobile web just don't have auto complete. If you type it manually (like everyone did before auto complete existed) the ping works just fine.

Comment: @sha is this really a duplicate? I didn't see this question as a feature request, but as a support question.

Comment: @Pat this is a corner case in my opinion. The root cause of the OP's confusion is that there is no auto complete for comment replies in mobile web

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ping a user you should start with `@`. For my name `@pat` is sufficient.

So:

- Always start with the `@` symbol;
- Names are not matched case sensitive. No leave out spaces though;
- You don't need the full name or use the <kbd>tab</kbd> key to 'select' a name, three letters are enough to ping a user;
- It does work perfectly from the mobile site, it just lacks auto-complete on the name.

Comment: Thank you! The supposed duplicate didn't answer these