# How about markup for usernames?

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts

Instead of just simply pasting a link to a user profile or tediously writing `[name](link)` why don't we have markup that will dynamically insert the current name of the user and a link to their profile? Two ideas are

- `@u34537` (u to define user and not post)

  or
- `:user34537:`

Comment: sort of suggested in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4798/ and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/

Comment: Lifehacker.com added this a while back.. it automatically added the name of the person you are replying to when you click 'Reply to'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be especially practical for comments, for one. When users change their names, some comments become useless.
Also, it will allow users to be notified for comments with their names.

Answer (score 2):

Can you give an example of when this would be used?  Surely one doesn't need to link to a user's profile page that often.

**Edit**: ah, you're wanting better notifications on comments. I'm not sure if you realize that addressing a comment "@Name" doesn't actually notify them that there was a reply -- only the author of the question/answer the comment is on will receive a notification.  However, adding a feature to notify all previous commenters has been requested many times previously: [Make recent activity and responses show new comments on questions/answers I have commented on (even if I don't own them)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have)

Comment: One User is 'OMG Ponies' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994143/incremental-backups-on-sql-server-and-mysql/ He may want to change his name. I could want a lazy or practical way to link him. But Kobi had a good idea about alerting. OMG Ponies was interested in my question and replied.