# Add support for linking "@username" in comments

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, comments, display-names, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Let’s make it easier to reply within comments!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4798/lets-make-it-easier-to-reply-within-comments)

As many people know, users will post comments, and refer to other users by name using the "@username" syntax. It would be nice to be able to create links to a user's profile by either of the following ways:

- Pick from a list of matching usernames when an "@" symbol is typed in a comment (similar to Facebook status updates)
- Be able to drag-and-drop a username/gravatar from the page into a comment

Since the StackOverflow sites allow you to change your display name, often times past comments will be left in a "corrupt" state - comments may refer to you by "@oldName", even after you've chnaged your name to "@newName". Allowing the linking of usernames would keep comments up-to-date even after name changes - "@newName" would always be shown.

Comment: The name changing isn't that much of a problem anywhere else but on meta, is it? And meta is, well, meta ...

Comment: I originally used a handle, but quickly realized I'd prefer to use my name.  I can imagine there are others who would like to switch, but realized that too late, and now feel stuck as they don't want to break anything.  People like "Johannes Schaub - litb" clearly wanted a change with the least breakage, for example. So while it isn't *much* of a problem... I think users would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Perhaps making the names on posts be static?  (Therefore nothing ever breaks.)  Or including both name-when-posting and current name.

Comment: @balpha - Just curious, why would Meta be more affected by name edits than SO, for example? I'm new to actually participating here, so I might just be missing something.

Comment: It's common to change your name on meta for humorous affect; at least *much* more popular than on SOFU.

Comment: @Roger Pate - +1 I see, thanks!

Comment: Ever changing: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/26518#26518

Comment: @random - +1 for the chuckles :)

Comment: @Spacklepants do you think my real name is sockpuppet? Last week it was I hate haikus

Comment: A much better suggestion is covered at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have

Answer (score 0):

Usually when someone addresses another user within the same question thread, the referred user would have left an answer and/or a comment and/or the question itself. Hence chances are there is/are already links to his/her profile.

I do find it a nice feature but I has a hunch the addtional server load might not be able to justify it.

I may be wrong though.