# Changing Username - would editing other user's posts be appropriate if they refer to the old username?

Tags: discussion, edits, display-names

Curious how this might be perceived by the community...

Let's say I wanted to change my username from "Yoooder" to "Millllller"... changing my name is simple in StackOverflow, however let's say other user's mentioned "Yoooder" in their comments.  Would it be OK for me to take the time to update their mention to use my updated name (rather than having them mention a no-longer-existant username)?

Or... would it likely be perceived as edit-spamming?

Comment: As an aside: that's exactly why I very much appreciate it when people just refer to @Arjan instead of my full name (which might not really be my full name to start with...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, given that you can't edit other people's comments, it's all a bit hypothetical.  However, I'd say editing answers where it would help with clarity would be acceptable (although probably a lot of work).

There have been other discussions about this previously, BTW:

- [Change all @username references in comments when a user changes their name?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31851/change-all-username-references-in-comments-when-a-user-changes-their-name)
- [Add support for linking "@username" in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34867/add-support-for-linking-username-in-comments)

Comment: good point, I'd thought I'd earned the ability to edit other comments when I passed the 3000 point mark--but nope, you're right I can only edit my own comments until someone else comments after me.  *bleh*

Comment: @Y aka M: no, you can edit your own comments during 5 minutes after posting, regardless what happens after you commented.

Comment: ahhh... obviously I haven't paid much attention to the specifics of comment editing :)