# When using @ to talk to someone who's commented, will he get notified?

Tags: support, comments, comment-replies

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Notify user when their name is mentioned in comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2035/notify-user-when-their-name-is-mentioned-in-comment)
>   [Make recent activity and responses show new comments on questions/answers I have commented on (even if I don’t own them)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have)

Can I get my message through to the one I want to talk to?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34867/add-support-for-linking-username-in-comments-closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yep**, see [Make recent activity and responses show new comments on questions/answers I have commented on (even if I don't own them)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have)