# If I delete my Stack Overflow account, will all my questions be deleted?

Tags: support, questions, deleted-accounts

If I delete my Stack Overflow account, will all my questions be deleted which I have asked on SO. Due to privacy I need to delete all my questions, is it possible?

Comment: First of all, you can't delete the account yourself.

Comment: No, deletion won't delete the questions, but you can change your display name and the rest of the profile information to anonymize your account.

Comment: Nope. Bad news: the Internet is forever.

Comment: And if it isn't Stack Overflow that makes the connection, then one of the copy cat sites might still continue doing it even if content were deleted. (See also [Is it bad to use your “real name” as your user name?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69256/is-it-bad-to-use-your-real-name-as-your-user-name))

Comment: The problem is from there , anyone can come to My SO page and see what questions i have asked (like my company bad manager , new job suggestion) and can guess how i feel in my current company . is there any way to delete few questions

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible.

But, if your account gets deleted the questions and answers will linger on without an associated account. This is to preserve as much information as possible. If you *really* need to get rid of all your questions and answers, then you need to contact the team and request it. Though, they don't like such requests because it means that you're taking away valuable information from the community forever.

The best way for all of us would be to make your account anonymous and then request to remove the account without removing the questions and answers.

Comment: By Anonymous u mean that my all questiosn will shows username="Anonymous" or my username stays same . any example of questions , where user is deleted

Comment: @Mirror51: No, the last set Displayname will be shown without a link or Gravatar. The name will be grayed out.

Comment: I think if i can use the same username which is most widely used at SO then it will be difficult for someone to find other posts  by that name . Am i correct. or still there be something which can find questions only that greyed out user

Comment: @Mirror51: Sounds like good approach to me.

Comment: @Mirror51 - If you're talking about copying someone else's username so that your questions appear to be from that person, please don't. "Anonymous User" or something other than your own name will work fine.