# Would it be OK to switch from the alias I used when I signed up to my actual name?

Tags: support, display-names

As the activity piles up over the past 1+ years I'm starting to view it as a potential resume building thing and wishing I had used my real name.

Any issues (and is it possible) to switch it?

Comment: Possible issues, non-technical: [Is it bad to use your “real name” as your user name?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69256/is-it-bad-to-use-your-real-name-as-your-user-name)

Comment: I guess I'm thinking my name is unique enough that i feel like people i've known over the years might recognize me and say "hi" as opposed to the arbitrary name i was using before...

Answer (score 4):

Yes it would be OK. You account is tied to your id not your name.

When any question/answer of yours is viewed the name will update.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to change your user name in your profile and you're done.

It might be confusing if you change your user name all the time, but [even trusted users don't care](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/26518/170332).

Comment: yea, i'll just do it once, and i surely don't think i'm so important as to cause an upheaval :)

Comment: Name changes are rate limited - to once per 30 days for this very reason