# Link and auto-complete @ mentions in comments

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

It was only after getting a warning with the following message:

> Only one additional @user can be notified; the post owner will always
>   be notified

that I realized using the `@` syntax actually had any effect other than being a "standard" from Twitter and such. It would therefore be nice if typing `@` into a comment first gave you auto-complete (with most weight to the people already involved in the discussion), and next actually made `@name` into a link when the comment was rendered.

I guess this is a feature that isn't meant to be discovered by accident (like I did), so it would be nice if it was advertised like I'm suggesting above so people use it more consciously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm declining this because it's two requests in one, and:

1. I don't agree with making comment @name mentions links at all (in fact, I violently disagree with that),
2. comment @name completion is [already in place here on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53404/tab-name-completion-for-comments-please), and will be rolled out network-wide very soon.

Comment: Why do you violently disagree with linking mentions? How about just presenting them so you know they're different from regular text? They're parsed by the system, like backticks, indentation, etc., so it makes sense from a usability perspective to do something visually with them. Even just wrapping them with a span that had a tooltip would be better than the absolute nothing you have now.

Comment: @asb This should really have been closed as a dupe; search.