# Quickly respond to @user in comment

Tags: feature-request, comments

I'm not sure how to state this in the title the right way. Please, feel free to edit it if you can say it a better way.

Is there any way to quickly respond to a user (either a guy posting a comment, the OP or an answer poster), such as CTRL + clicking his name? I currently have to copy / paste his name and then add the @.

If there is not such feature, I think having it would be also an easier way to have a feature like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have), since the link to a user could have an HTML class (or something like that, I'm not that advanced on HTML but I think you get the idea) that identifies the link as link to a user. This class would be applied to links to user anywhere (including @username links in comments of course). This way, the system would easily distinguish when a user is being referenced (perhaps another attribute could be used to identify the referenced user).

Comment: Type @ and the first letter, then [select it from the popup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53404/tab-name-completion-for-comments-please). Note: Doing this won't work for the OP, since that [would be stripped out](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation) anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find [this script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2051/reply-links-on-comments) useful.

Or just use [tab completion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53404/tab-name-completion-for-comments-please) as ughoavgfhw suggests. Boy, *there's* a name you don't want to type from memory!

Be aware in both cases that [@-replies are fairly limited!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: Hey! It's not *that* hard to type. I do it all the time!