# Why can't I tag certain people in comments?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

I fully expected to find this question already asked after typing it in, so if there is a duplicate somewhere please direct me to it...

I can't seem to tag some people in comments.  I would have said that it was only people with spaces in their name, but I was actually able to tag someone with a space in their name just a minute ago.

Comment: See also the usage notes in [Tab name completion for comments please!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53404/tab-name-completion-for-comments-please/106450#106450)

Comment: Not only can you only notify one person per comment, the `@name` will be automatically removed if you're trying to notify the only other person in the conversation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can tag only one person in comments with @. More about how comments work in [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to pay attention to when it happens in the future to see if it's because of one of those rules.

Comment: shouldn't we be able to tag the OP author of a given question or answer on which we're commenting? I type it manually, but after I save, the tag is removed >:0