# Tiny bug in user tagging suggestion in comments

Tags: support, comments, comment-replies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tab name completion for comments please!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53404/tab-name-completion-for-comments-please)

In this question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759873/) try and add a comment to my answer and try and quote the guy who asked the question. Now, usually entering @ will give you a little hint to enter in the user name of the user in your comments, but in this case it doesn't.

I suspect this is because the user's username is in Chinese? Very small bug, but I thought it was worth highlighting nonetheless :)

Comment: You have to type at least one letter following the @ sign before suggestions kick in. It works fine for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/nCqFk.jpg

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ Ah I see, I don't have Chinese characters on my keyboard so I couldn't try that. Put this as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: It should work even if you copy-paste the first character.

Comment: @PopularDemand Yeah it does :)

Comment: @PopularDemand: I'm now going to make the first character in my username a zero-width one just to bug people ;-)