# How do I autocomplete a user tag with a keypress, not a mouse click?

Tags: support, comment-replies, autocomplete

If I am typing a user tag, e.g. `@Noble`, and the autocomplete box appears, I want to complete the name with a keypress, not a mouse click. I've tried tab, up arrow, and right arrow, none of which have worked. Is this possible?

Comment: "Tab" works for me. What's your browser/OS?

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce Has it always been like this? It might be just my browser then. It wouldn't work for me yesterday (actually, that was probably Tuesday), but then again Yosemite froze that day as well and I had to restart my computer. Tab works now (using Firefox)... weird.

Comment: TMK, it has worked that way as long as I've been here.

Comment: Well then, it's Murphy's Law that when I finally post a question after being so fed up with this not working... it works. I'll try this on my Firefox at home and see if I can reproduce it there.

Comment: This has apparently existed [since September, 2011](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106450/262755).

Comment: My apologies then. Maybe it's just one of the [many](http://superuser.com/questions/616861/how-do-i-fix-github-icons-octicons-on-firefox) [things](http://superuser.com/questions/720821/how-do-i-fix-custom-font-icons-on-firefox-again) wrong with my Firefox profile at home.