# A small reply icon for comments

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Let's make it easier to reply within comments!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4798/lets-make-it-easier-to-reply-within-comments)

I think the site would be helped by having a small reply icon that appears on hover.  Clicking it would start a new comment with @original poster already typed it.  It's much better than having to write it out manually, particularly if it's a long name.

EDIT: I see that auto-completion has been implemented on meta (not sure when it went live) - that's half the battle.

Comment: The user script ["Reply" links on comments](http://stackapps.com/questions/2051/reply-links-on-comments) adds this feature.

Comment: Good idea; not however that you can abbreviate, @Angry should work for example.

Comment: @JeremyBanks: I use it, its pretty good and hasn't broken in a long time.

Comment: @JeremyBanks The user script is nice and the attached chrome compatible code is pretty clever too.

Comment: It was already proposed and declined by Jeff, don't think he changed his mind since then..

Comment: ↵ do you mean this one?

Comment: @genesis-φ yes.