# format @user-id in comments

Tags: feature-request, comments

Two suggestions on comments/commenting on question and answers:

1. imo, it would look nice if a user's ID that is prefixed with @ in a comment was formatted subtly different (color? bold?) from the other text in the comment. For example:
   "@liao: so is not so-so" could be "***@liao***: so is not so-so" (no pun intended :)
2. when creating a comment, it would be useful (no proof, just feels "right") to ask the commenter "who" the comment is directed at.
   a. "who" = user id picked from asker and other commenters on the quesion
   b. in case of a comment referencing multiple commenters, point #1 may help instead?

Feel free to trample on all the above - they are just thoughts i had in the short time i've been using this site, so i had to at least put it "out <strike>there</strike> here".

Comment: looks like this question is similar to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9652/name-comments-should-link-to-the-named-persons-profile-like-twitter. Didn't see it in the search results before I posted..

Comment: @-1'nner: if you read the post i mention, you will notice that it is in the same "vein", but not the same. would really like to know why this question was downvoted.

Comment: @unknown (yahoo): I'm not the -1'nner; but on meta, it's quite common to downvote feature requests that you don't agree with. That might have been the reason.

Comment: a lesson learned! - thanks for the clarification. i would expect that downvoting on meta would be more "stringent" - as in requiring a comment for it, especially for a question tagged "feature-request". maybe i just feature-request-ed again ... why post it though, cos it may just get downvoted again. but then again, i will post it, cos after all, votes really dont matter.

Answer (score 3):

As for your second point, I think this might encourage a more threaded discussion, which I believe Jeff & Joel specifically don't want (and I see their point here).

If you start responding to commenters, the Q&A part of the site may degrade.

Comment: gotcha. for one, you mean it would encourage flame-wars type of thing, correct?

Comment: Right, for one thing. It would also encourage less harmful discussion, that is still not in the interest of quickly asking a question and getting an answer. The focus would instead be shifted to the discussion.

Comment: your comment should be in the "etiquette faq", if there is one.