# Are comments no longer appearing on the Recent Activity page?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments, recent-activity

Are comments no longer creating entries on the Recent Activity page? I used to park on that page to see if anything has happened recently on a question I asked, but while watching a particular question from that page and seeing nothing happen, I drilled into the question and found several comments. I thought it used to list comments here along with the answers and what I've commented on. Has this been removed?

Comment: I think the issues goes beyond comments.  I'm getting points but don't see them in the recent activity page also.  There be gremlins at work...

Comment: Recent activity has be very slow for me of late. I sometimes get notified more than an hour after I've seen the triggering post.

Answer (score 1):

My comments are showing up fine on my Recent Activity page (the page you go after clicking the envelope). I am able to see any comment replies people leave for me there.

On the Recent tab of my profile, I can see comments I make, but there are no comments that other users leave for me on my content.

Comment: Maybe what I'm expecting are the comments to the answers more so than the question. For a post I created today (#1189208), on my Recent Activity page I can see the one comment on the question, but none of the comments on the Jon Skeet answer. Maybe I'm asking too much, but I would assume most of the comments would be on potential answers and would as such be important enough to display on the activity page.

Comment: gfrizzle: You will never be able to see comments made on posts that were not made by you. You can see comments on your questions and your answers, but not on someone else's questions and answers (even if the answer is answering one of your questions)

Comment: That's too bad - that's where a lot of back and forth happens when exploring an answer someone provided. It would be a shame for someone to comment it's not seen because the question owner don't look at the actual question page again.

Comment: perhaps if this (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9652/name-comments-should-link-to-the-named-persons-profile-like-twitter), or this (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have) feature gets implemented, you would see that back-and-forth

Answer (score 0):

check the date ranges. Try clicking on "today" or "yesterday". I believe the code tries to infer a "last time you were here" date which isn't always correct.