# Change default username from "Unknown" to "User{number}"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, new-users, display-names

I just saw a user named: .yahoo.co.jpaqwsykcj3aulh3h1k0cy6nzs3isj

Could new users be named according to their user-number, or something other than "Unknown"? Perhaps **User1234567** instead? It would be less awkward to address them in answers and comments.

Additionally, I often times have to check profiles to make sure users aren't abusing the system, since I find many of the same questions from "unknown (google)" from time to time. That, or I'll mistakenly think I've helped the user on a similar issue in the past, and assume the user has knowledge that he or she does not have.

Comment: Best new feature request so far this year.

Comment: Thank god we are only in january.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know if you guys fully understand the ramifications of this change.

Remember our friend [~quack](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/137184)?

Think about how his user "name" exists, and why. (Also consider how you won't be "addressing" users like this at all, really..)

In the meantime, I enabled this for Google and Yahoo only.

Comment: ~quack is a special case, though. +1 for the change.

Comment: ... wow.  thanks, jeff.  i... had no idea you cared.  :)

Comment: I just thought it was hilarious that you were so dedicated to that squiggle. :)

Comment: You stole my bounty :(

Comment: I call no fair. The community clearly thought I had the better answer. Hrmph. :-)

Comment: @Jeff: What happened with `~quack`?

Comment: ~quack died and was reborn like a phoenix. But not in Arizona. @jos

Answer (score 28):

This makes sense; and it's easier to for people to tie it to a person later on, even if their name changes.

For instance, in comments:

```
User1010101: I don't know how to do this.
George: @User1010101: You do it this way.
```

Later on, even if `User1010101` changes his name, I can still look at my old comment and trace who I was talking to to that `UserID`.

Even better, it'd be nice if we could (and there's a meta discussion out about this) just put `{s:UserID}` in a comment and have it render whatever name they're using currently.  If their UserID was in a hover-tooltip, then it'd be easy to grab.  There are some edge cases with this, but it'd at least get the hardcoded names out.

Unfortunately, yes, it would add some processing time and probably slow down the requests a little bit -- I don't know by how much though.

Comment: What you say is related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35755/small-but-annoying-problem-references-to-other-answers-are-lost-after-name-chang and to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9652/name-comments-should-link-to-the-named-persons-profile-like-twitter

Comment: Also related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have

Comment: It wouldn't have to slow down requests - just do it on the client via a javascript ajax call.  Of course, you could argue that still slows things down, but at least now it's only indirectly.

Comment: It wouldn't even be hard to find comments that said "User1010101" and change them to display the user's new name. Or, alternatively, have SO automatically change `User{ID}` to the User's current name in comments. _That_ would be nice.

Answer (score 4):

I agree

<sub>(can I have the bounty now?)</sub>

Comment: It seems your username is getting in the way of you getting the bounty. HUMOROUS BUT ULTIMATELY MEANINGLESS META DOWNVOTE! MUAHAHAHA!

Comment: @Cha, he can explicitly award it to me (and please, don't downvote me, I'm the Downvoter, not the Downvotee (it hurts))

Comment: Karma​​!

Answer (score 1):

I am still seeing that username [yahoo-co-jpaqwsykcj3aulh3h1k0cy6nzs3isj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85509/yahoo-co-jpaqwsykcj3aulh3h1k0cy6nzs3isj)

Is that really **status-completed**?

Comment: @S Mark: I believe that's for new users only.

Comment: Ah, ok, you're right, but still wondering what happened to that username, I don't think he named himself like that.

Comment: @S. Mark - [You would be surprised](http://superuser.com/users/21952/user21952-is-a-great-name).

Comment: @Gnoupi, :D Yes, but that user filled name field, so thats look like intentional, but the one with yahoo-co-jp..... is no name actually, I guess system automatically choose it.