# How are users with usernames such as userxxxx (x are numbers) created?

Tags: support, display-names

Did they chose this username, is this some kind of temporary account or they did not fill the username box?

Comment: I saw now... it was about the same aspect. Shall I delete my question now?

Comment: I'd recommend keeping it; duplicates are useful to keep around, to help people find the answer easier

Comment: This question's answers seem slightly more informative than the original's, at least regarding to how the names are chosen for an empty field.

Answer (score 7):

That's the default username.

Each user is assigned a User ID - you can see yours if you go to [your user ID](https://stackexchange.com/users/current) and look at the URL bar. Mine is 3203697 on the whole network, 186134 on Ask Ubuntu and 2808510 on Stack Overflow.

This is a sequential number, for each person who signed up.

The latest (as of writing) is [tuan anh tran](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/320271/tuan-anh-tran) - at user ID 320271.

However, you're only assigned it once, so if you sign up to 4 sites, your username will be User{number} and that number will be from the first site you signed up to.

You can change this to be a custom name - and that name can be the same as someone else's.

Answer (score 2):

Those are the default usernames given by stack exchange application.

To know more details, we should start with stack exchange signup process.

[image: stack exchange signup form]

A user name is an optional field in stack exchange application form. 
If a user doesn't give any name in the signup form, then

- stack exchange tries to read it from his open ID info(ex: Google, Yahoo, facebook).
- If above step fails, then stack exchange puts user{stackexchange sequence number} as user name.

Earlier these usernames are like **yahoo.co.jpaqwsykcj3aulh3h1k0cy6nzs3isj**

But now, Stack exchange is defaulting this anonymous users with a sequence number based on a community [suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35839/change-default-username-from-unknown-to-usernumber).

A user can update this default name using profile settings page.

Comment: It's not random is it...? The user ID is sequential... E.g. this is the most recently signed up user: http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/320271/tuan-anh-tran

Comment: @Metasomatism,. You are correct, it is sequential `stackexchange` site user id. I was confused when I tested with a dummy account. Dummy account redirected to stack overflow.  In that site, stackoverflow profile id & user id are different

Comment: @Metasomatism, updated my answer. Thanks for correction.

Comment: @Metasomatism, [above image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/opE43.png) in my answer is too fresh. I have taken screenshot today morning. You are showing login page. that's not signup form.