# Teensy bug: @replies do not change on username change

Tags: bug, display-names, comment-replies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change all @username references in comments when a user changes their name?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31851/change-all-username-references-in-comments-when-a-user-changes-their-name)

This is extremely trivial, but worth reporting (could be a side-effect of a larger bug)
When a user changes their username, @replies to that user are not changed.

This comment for example: [How would a black hole power plant work?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20813/how-would-a-black-hole-power-plant-work#comment48549_20818) . It was addressed to the OP, [AlanSE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/1255/alanse). He has since changed his username, but the @reply stays the same.

The only thing that this effects is the ability of another user to follow a comment thread; which is pretty trivial, especially given that the comments aren't for long discussions.

Comment: This is SE-wide idea, so moving to meta.SO.

Comment: I think it would be impractical to fix this, for fairly little benefit.

Comment: Also see: [Changing comments to reference merged accounts or edited usernames](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111874/changing-comments-to-reference-merged-accounts-or-edited-usernames), [Small but annoying problem: References to other answers are lost after name changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35755/small-but-annoying-problem-references-to-other-answers-are-lost-after-name-chan), etc

Comment: Since it was migrated; I see this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31851/change-all-username-references-in-comments-when-a-user-changes-their-name