# Name change retroactive in comments, but not in chat

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, chat, display-names

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37126976/798371), I exchanged some comments with someone going by the name "user6292850 and continued that discussion [in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111482/discussion-between-wbt-and-user6292850).  Later, I returned to see that the comments were now attributed to a user named "[sleep tight pupper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6292850/sleep-tight-pupper)" in the comments section, but NOT in the continuation in chat (and [not in the @user6292850 part of my comments responding to that user's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31851/change-all-username-references-in-comments-when-a-user-changes-their-name)).
Does it make sense to have the names change in chat as well, if it's being changed in the comments?

Alternatively, does it make sense to not change the names in either place, to be consistent with both chat and other commenters' references?

Comment: You mean this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35755/small-but-annoying-problem-references-to-other-answers-are-lost-after-name-chan ?

Comment: @Catija  I picked the [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31851/change-all-username-references-in-comments-when-a-user-changes-their-name) that had more attention and a well-received detailed answer describing the same problem as that one.  This question here is about the inconsistency between how attribution changes for *comments* but not for the continuation of those comments in *chat*, rather than the inconsistency between comment attributions and references to other usernames in later comments, though the suggestion in the last line would fix both of those inconsistencies.

Comment: Chat profile is taking long time to synchronize, sometimes even whole day. But eventually it will, then it will be "retroactive", as you call it.